# jquery datatables- Maximum number of columns in one datatable

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins, datatables

Hi I'm trying to develop a UI for an oracle table which has around 40 columns/fields using jquery datatbles plugin. I'm able to display upto 18 columns, but after that it's not working. Is anyone else faced the same issue before? Please advice me on this i'm pretty new with jquery.

```
`Sorry for that...
```

when i'm trying to create a UI for my oracle table, when i configure it for 18 columns(any 18) i can see my UI is working perfectly. But if i add one more column and update the configuration my UI is not loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#reports").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/databaseInterface/DataSource",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                          {  "sName": "ID",
                             "bSearchable": false,
                             "bSortable": false,
                             "bVisible": false
                                 },
                  { "sName": "name" },
                  { "sName": "sname" },
                  { "sName": "address" },
                  { "sName": "city" },
                  { "sName": "post code" },
                  { "sName": "age" },
                  { "sName": "major" },
                  { "sName": "grade" },
                  { "sName": "Elect1" },
                  { "sName": "Elect2" },
                  { "sName": "Elect3" },
                  { "sName": "Elect4" },
                  { "sName": "Elect5" },
                  { "sName": "Assig1" },
                  { "sName": "Assig2" },
                  { "sName": "Assig3" },
                  { "sName": "Assig4" },
                  { "sName": "Assig5" }
                 ]
     }).makeEditable({
            "aoColumns": [
                          {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}
                      ]
                      });
    });
    </script>
```

this is my sample code which is working properly, and is i add { "sName": "Status" } at the end, and update my datasource with the corresponding value it's not displaying aything in my UI.
`

jquery 1.8, java 5 and also jquery editable datable plugin

I'm trying to display my oracle table like a datatable shown in this website 
[datatable reference that i'm using](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html)

Comment: Post something you already have before people start to downvote your question. You see, the information you've posted is not enough to anyone give a right answer. Alongside the code, please try to inform the versions your are using, like the jQuery version, the plugin version, if there's an example in another site and such

Comment: Are you using a comma after the line { "sName": "Assig5" } and before adding { "sName": "Status" } at the end?

Comment: did you add the column header `<th>Staus</th>` too?

Comment: yes i did, Allan's solution resolved my issue. I was using GET instead of POST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely the problem is that your server is rejecting GET requests which have more than a certain number of characters. By default DataTables sends server-side processing requests as GET. To change to POST use the sServerMethod option - http://datatables.net/ref#sServerMethod .

Comment: This explains so much :)  Now I know why my various implementations of datatables have seemingly random success rates, even when I am copying and pasting code.